# How to use symbols in name of form select area?

Tags: php, html, forms, url, symbols

Iv got a form and I need to put = and & in the name of the Select area which will then later be displayed as a URL link.  However if I put = or & the URL displays = as %3D and the & sign is displayed as %26

I have this so far

```
    <form method="get" name="FormFilter">
    <select name="condition=<?php echo $condition; ?>&order" onChange="document.forms['FormFilter'].submit()">
    <option value ="ASC">Newest</option>
    <option value="DESC">Oldest</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

and it shows the URL as

> browse.php?condition%3Difquestions%26order=DESC

Iv tried using `&#61;` and `$amp;` but they dont work.  How can I get it to work?
Thanks

Comment: well basically its a filter to sort a list of results from a database.  However iv got one page that will show different results depending on what iv got called the $condition,  I also then have pages, so ill add more to this later once iv got this fixed.  But basically I want it to say browse.php?condition=ifquestions&order=DESC its all for the URL so that uses dont have to keep re-entering data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form method="get" name="FormFilter">
    <select name="order" onChange="document.forms['FormFilter'].submit()">
        <option value="ASC">Newest</option>
        <option value="DESC">Oldest</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="condition" value="<?=$condition?>" />
</form>
```